# How do I remove a disk image that I created myself?

Tags: macos, disk-utility, disk-image

I went to disk utility and created a new image with 1.5 GB of my hard disk.

Now I want to remove it and have all the space back for my Macintosh HD. Nothing seems to work. If I eject it, it's not completely gone because I can still go to File -> Open Disk Image and I can still see that image.

How should I completely remove it and restore everything to what it was before?

Comment: Firstly, welcome to Ask Different! :)  I hope you come to find this site has a lot to offer! In case you haven't already, it's worth taking the time to read the [tour](https://apple.stackexchange.com/tour). All the best!

Comment: Just checking in - did my answer help or are you still stuck?

Comment: Oh yeah your answer totally worked and made things clear for me. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

The disk image itself is basically treated as a *file* by Finder. So, after ejecting the disk image (assuming you had it mounted), all you need to do is delete the disk image like like you would any other file.

For example, right-click on the disk image and select the **Move to Trash** option and then empty the trash. Likewise, you can just select it in Finder and use the <kbd>command</kbd><kbd>delete</kbd> keyboard shortcut to move it to trash and then empty it.